# Is Word2vec memory and time consuming?

Tags: nlp, data-science, word2vec

I am trying to train a Word2Vec model using neural Networks. My question is as follows:

Correct me if I am wrong: word2vec uses as input text, which doesn't have the same order of magnitude as images ( with respect to memory) ? Does this imply that there is no need to use GPU for training a word2vec model , and by the way a 64Go Virtual cloud machine is enough to make training? Text uses for training can't exced 5-10Go?

Answer (score 2):

You can train word2vec models on gigabytes, terabytes, petabytes of text if you'd like. Any amount of text, really, if you're patient enough.

The model itself should generally be kept in RAM for efficiency, but the size of the model depends on the number of *unique words* that the model is learning, and the chosen number of dimensions for those words, *not* the total amount of training data.

So, you could stream a corpus of 100s of gigabytes of text from disk, to train a small-vocabulary, small-dimension word2vec model using just 1GB of RAM.

But alternatively, you could have a corpus of just a few GB that has millions of unique words you want to retain, and train large-dimensional vectors for - and the word2vec model for that might not fit in a 64GB or 128GB RAM machine.

So there's no one answer for "word2vec" – it depends on your corpus, desired vocabulary, and other chosen parameters.

GPUs can help with certain kinds of calculations and workloads. They're often not optimal for word2vec-style training, as a GPU's on-board memory, and memory-bandwidth, can be limited in ways that make large-vocabulary, large-dimensional models hit bottlenecks.